# not able to render api results in react

Tags: reactjs, api

This is code and I am trying to access the result from the api but I am not able to show it on my page.
The results are visible in console but not in page.
I have tried few things but it hasn't worked for me.
I am stuck on this only for the last few days.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const SearchArea = () => {

const [input,setInput] = useState("");   
const [results,setResults] = useState(null)

const onInputChange = (ev) => {
setInput(ev.target.value)
}

const onSearch = () => {

    fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${input}`)
    .then(r=>r.json())
    .then(result=>{ 
        setResults(result) ;
        console.log(result.result.full_short_link)})

}


const onKeyDown= (ev) =>{
if(ev.keyCode === 13){
    onSearch();
}

}


const renderResult = () => {

if(results && results.ok === 0){
    return <div>No link to convert.</div>
}


if(results && results.length > 0){
    return <div>{results.map((item)=><div>{item.results.result.full_short_link}</div>)}</div>
}


return null
}



return (
    <div>
        <div className="search-bar">
            <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDown}  onChange={onInputChange} value={input} className="searching" placeholder="Shorten a link here..."></input>
            <button className="short-butt" onClick={onSearch}>Shorten It!</button>
            <div>{renderResult()}</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
)
}

export default SearchArea
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, it seems that you are trying to show MULTIPLE results from the API. So you must start with an array instead of `null` in the state.

```js
const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
```

Then for every response from the API, you could either `push` into the `results` with `results.push()` (not recommended) or you could do spread operator like below (more recommended):

```js
fetch(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${input}`)
  .then((r) => {
    return r.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.result.full_short_link);
    setResults([...results, result.result.full_short_link]); //spread operator
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Later you can use `map` on showing the results.

```js
if(results && results.length > 0){
    return <div>{results.map((item)=><div>{item.results.result.full_short_link}</div>)}</div>
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

You can see the code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-link-shorter-7ro9o?file=/index.js

Comment: Your explanation was up-to the point. It helped me a lot. Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to Upvote and "Accept as Best Answer". It means a lot to me